# Getting: "ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@vercel/analytics/react'.(import/no-unresolved)" but package & path inside is actually present

Tags: npm, next.js, eslint, vercel, typescript-eslint

As the title says, ESLint is complaining with this error message:

```
ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@vercel/analytics/react'.(import/no-unresolved)
```

In the line: `import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';`

When following the instructions from this [Vercel quickstart guide](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/analytics/audiences/quickstart#add-the-%60analytics%60-component-to-your-app), using Next.js.

To sum up, the instructions are:

1- install package via NPM

```
npm install @vercel/analytics
```

2- in `/pages/_app.tsx` file, import it:

```
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Analytics />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

My packages used:

```
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",

    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.2.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.10.2",
```

The NPM package installed, has this folder structure:

```
/node_modules/@vercel
  analytics/
    dist/
      react/
        index.cjs
        index.d.ts
        index.js
      index.cjs
      index.d.ts
      index.js
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    ...
```

Notice how the path in node_modules *actually* is '@vercel/analytics/dist/react' rather than just '@vercel/anaylitics/react' as the instructions state to do in the code to use it.

**But**, when CTRL+click'ing on the variable imported `Analytics`, my IDE properly navigates me to the definition in node_modules, to the file `@vercel/analytics/dist/react/index.d.ts`, which is defined like so:

```
// ./node_modules/@vercel/analytics/dist/react/index.d.ts

// ...

declare function Analytics(props: AnalyticsProps): JSX.Element;

export { Analytics };
```

My ESLint config related to the `import/` module is

```js
settings: {
  'import/resolver': {
    node: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      paths: ['src'],
    },
  },
},
```

If I import it as this instead:

```
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/dist/react'
```

**then** ESlint doesn't complain, **but** TSC does, with this error message:

```
TS2305: Module '"@vercel/analytics/dist/react"' has no exported member 'Analytics'.
```

Which also doesn't seem to make sense as the IDE is still finding the definition, and I can also see how the `export { Analytics }`  line is there, so it *should* work...

What ESlint config or steps should I take differently to make this work without any lint/compiler errors?

Comment: Have the same issue but even the vercel ci crashed with an error because of this. Very strange!
I guess, @vercel has to roll out a fix for this in the package?

Answer (score 4):

When using `eslint` you will need to use the plugin: [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript) with version `3.1.0` or later.

We also merged this version into `eslint-config-next` in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/43010). So this issue should also be resolved by upgrading to the [latest package (13.0.4)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-next?activeTab=explore)

There is also a issue on our Github repo which with the solution: https://github.com/vercel/analytics/issues/18#issuecomment-1318424277

Answer (score 2):

I have a question into vercel for a solution as I have the same issue. Probably to be expected since this is a beta product. I added the following line to my _app.js file in the meantime which allowed me to bypass the linting error and deploy to vercel. I have tested and the analytics is showing so must simply be a bug.

```
...
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```json
//tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@vercel/analytics/react": ["./node_modules/@vercel/analytics/dist/react"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help... the error is related to ESlint, and this change affects the TS config/compiler only